# Exim condition failure "${env is not a known operator"

Tags: environment-variables, variable-substitution, exim

I am trying to substitute a hard-coded path in my Exim configuration file with a value taken from an environment variable, however I am getting an error I do not understand.

```
"${env" is not a known operator (or a } is missing in a variable reference)
```

This is the condition causing the error

```
condition = ${if !exists{${env{MAILPATH}{$value} fail }/$local_part} }
```

If I change the condition to this, then it works fine:

```
condition = ${if !exists{/srv/mail/$local_part} }
```

I cannot see the syntax error on the `${env` line, so could someone please point out what silly mistake I have made?

Comment: I can't see why the `env` is throwing an error. Personally I would have put the `/$local_part` inside the `env` expansion thus `${if !exists{ ${env{MAILPATH}{$value/$local_part} fail }}}` but I don't think that will fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chasing this myself for some time, I found that the `${env` operator only seems to have been added in the relatively recent exim4 version 4.86. Compare [here (4.85)](http://exim.org/exim-html-4.85/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html) and [here (4.86)](http://exim.org/exim-html-4.86/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html).

Unfortunately the latest version of exim4 available on debian jessie was 4.84, causing me similar pain until I found this.